# Qual a função em Python equivalente ao Crypt em PHP

Tags: python, python-2.7, criptografia

Tenho um programa em `PHP` que criptografa uma senha com o método `crypt`:

```
$crypt = '$1$/E0xe3/3$yPzJElk.aVSd5JoQTopDZ/';
if($crypt == crypt($_POST['key'],$crypt))
```

E com isso gero o seguinte hash dessa senha:

```
*$1$Mmd/1SKE$bE44ZNJgYXDjm10rUHC5L1*
```

Queria fazer gerar o mesmo `hash` em `Python`, mas não sei como.

O comando:

```
 *cat /etc/login.defs | grep ^ENCRYPT_METHOD*
```

Retorna `(*ENCRYPT_METHOD SHA512*)`

Comment: Você pode usar a lib [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html) pra gerar *hashs* do tipo que exemplificou.

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema, definindo o salt com o crypt.crypt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import crypt

hash = '$1$/E0xe3/3$yPzJElk.aVSd5JoQTopDZ/'
crypt.crypt('marcus.mann', hash)
```

Comment: Poderia adicionar uma explicação do seu código?

Comment: Ele primeiramente define o que ele quer criptografar no caso o 'marcus.mann' e logo após ele define o salt ou "método" de criptografia que sera utilizado